# Flutter get.create implementation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have a situation that only is fixed by get.create in getx package
I have the following code

```
class ShoppingBinding implements Bindings {
 @override
 void dependencies() {

  Get.create<ShoppingController>(() => ShoppingController()); 
   } 
}
```

but I don't know how to call this
thanks in advance

Comment: Get.find<ShoppingController>() should do it. Each time you will call this a new instance of controller would be created.

Answer (score 1):

you should create routing in GetMaterialApp :

```
  getPages: AppPages.pages,
  initialRoute: AppPages.INITIAL_ROUTE,
```

and in AppPages class :

```
GetPage(
    name: AppRoutes.ShoppingRouteName,
    page: () => ShoppingWidget(),
    binding: ShoppingBinding()),
```

Finally :

```
Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.ShoppingRouteName),
```

and in shopWidget :

```
class ShoppingWidget extends GetView<ShoppingController> {
```